# How do I return the values in descending order for the following quick sort code i wrote in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, quicksort

this is the code i have currently written for my quick sort algorithm. I want to return it in descending order

[image: this is the code i have currently written for my quick sort algorithm. I want to return it in descending order]

Comment: Have you tried reversing the `high.append(i)` with `low.apend(i)` and vice versaa

Comment: yes but it doesnt give a correct output

Comment: Can you please share the values for lst, and column

Comment: lst: [('history', 2), ('is', 3), ('an', 2), ('extremely', 1), ('important', 1), ('part', 2), ('of', 2), ('the', 7), ('human', 2), ('civilization', 1), ('our', 1), ('evolution', 2), ( 'from', 1), ('primate', 1), ('to', 2), ('homo', 1), ('sapiens', 1), ('provides', 1), ('critical', 1), ('information', 1), ('about', 1), ('fact', 1), ('a', 3), ('and', 3)]

Comment: the column number is 0

Comment: `[('to', 2), ('the', 7), ('sapiens', 1), ('provides', 1), ('primate', 1), ('part', 2), ('our', 1), ('of', 2), ('is', 3), ('information', 1), ('important', 1), ('human', 2), ('homo', 1), ('history', 2), ('from', 1), ('fact', 1), ('extremely', 1), ('evolution', 2), ('critical', 1), ('civilization', 1), ('and', 3), ('an', 2), ('about', 1), ('a', 3)]` is this the solution you're looking for?

Comment: @BestCompilations Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please check this link on how you can ask questions - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - Esp. DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.

Comment: Try again what Shaikh said. And remember: Your QuickSort implementation also takes a bool (look at the recursive calls).

Comment: @ShaikhAbuzar yess this is what i am looking for

Comment: @BestCompilations I have attached the code below, if you find it please select it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked the your code and attached it below:

```py
def quicksort(lst, column, descending=True):
    low = []
    high = []
    result = []

    if len(lst) <= 1:
        return lst

    if descending == True:
        pivot = lst[0][column]

        for i in lst:
            if i[column] == pivot:
                result.append(i)
            elif i[column] > pivot:
                low.append(i)
            elif i[column] < pivot:
                high.append(i)

        return quicksort(low, column) + result + quicksort(high, column)
```